# htpasswd: wrong credentials created

Tags: linux, fedora, .htpasswd

I was trying to setup svn on a machine running Linux Fedora 18. I created and added new users by using htpasswd. So basically what I did was:

```
$ htpasswd -c passwd admin.
```

where passwd is the file containing the username/password pairs. By default, htpasswd is supposed to use md5 to encrypt passwords. So, later when I tried to login, I couldn't, even though I supplied correct username and password. 
After trying different things, I went to some online md5 generator, typed in the same password. The resulting string was different from the one generated by htpasswd. I manually edited passwd file, put in the md5 password I got from the website and successfully logged in. Is there something wrong with htpasswd or there are some system setting which need to be fixed?

Comment: I suggest to try `-m  Force MD5 encryption of the password (default).` option for `htpasswd`. I thought it should be used by default though.

Comment: I tried using -m. It was no go (((

Comment: hashes generated by `htpasswd` are salted, of course you get different passwords. that alone doesn't say anything.

Comment: yes... that's right. But still why password generated by website works, while password generated by htpasswd doesn't. I am damn sure I entered right password.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

```
htpasswd -c passwdfile username
```

or

```
htpasswd -cb passwdfile username yourpassword
```

The default hash algorithm is MD5 since version 2.2.18 of apache (you can identify it by the $apr1$ prefix). Before that, the default hash was unix crypt, (without a prefix).
If your apache version is <2.2.18, you'd better force md5 with

```
htpasswd -cm passwdfile username
htpasswd -cbm passwdfile username yourpassword
```

Maybe after that you should check your passwdfile is correctly created (do you havec permissions etc).

When you generate an MD5 hash, with online tools or with the htpasswd command-line, it's different each time because it uses a random salt.